# Auto save form USING JSF

Tags: jsf, persistence

I have the following need:
I need to persist in DB the data input at the JSF form from time to time, i have ones thoughts but might be a litle "Bug friendly" or/and low performatic,
someone have already took success solving this problem with JSF ?

EDIT:
Anyone that has the same problema, tried to solve that problem saving the updates inputs using "onchange"? 
i think that this is the easier way to solve it , but i dont know if is a effective way to do it

Thank you'll in advance!

Comment: Hi, these are not the sort of questions to ask on stackoverflow. See [ask]. Break down your problem. Before 'persisting' you need to get the data from the client to the server either from time-to-time or per field if the input changed. For the latter there is 'ajax'. The only thing you still need then is to periodically store the server side values in the database which is not a jsf related problem. If you break down the problem and post what you tried, what the related problem is, people can comment on that. Cheers

Comment: I got it , thanks.

Comment: Try it... if it is effective for you, it **is** effective